# How to derive the sum-to-product formula for cos(a-b)-cos(a+b)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I know how to derive the sum-to-product formulas for cos+cos, sin+cos, and cos+sin. But I cannot seem to do it for cos-cos. My problem is the negative out front. I cannot product it from any of my proofs.

Here is my attempt:

I know that cos(a-b) = cosacosb + sinasinb
I know that cos(a+b) = cosacosb - sinasinb.
If I subtract these, I get cos(a-b)-cos(a+b) = 2sinasinb

However, my book tells me that cosa - cosb = -2sin(a+b / 2)sin(a-b /2)...

Where does the negative come from?

**additional effort**

My book also says I can make a + b = u and a - b = v. By adding and subtracting these from one another, this gets me u+v / 2 and u-v / 2. But none of those come with a negative that I can use to make sin(-x) = -sin(x).

Answer (score 2):

Put
$$a=u+v; \;\; b=u-v$$
then

$$u=\frac{a+b}{2};\;\;  v=\frac{a-b}{2}$$

$$\cos(a)-\cos(b)=$$
$$\cos(u+v)-\cos(u-v)=$$
$$\cos(u)\cos(v)-\sin(u)\sin(v)-$$
$$\cos(u)\cos(v)-\sin(u)\sin(v)=$$

$$-2\sin(u)\sin(v)=$$
$$-2\sin(\frac{a+b}{2})\sin(\frac{a-b}{2})$$

and you computed the opposite
$$\cos(u-v)-\cos(u+v)=$$
$$2\sin(u)\sin(v)$$

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing why mine is opposite. cos+cos has the form (sin(a-b)) - sin(a+b)). Only looking at the signs to identify the pattern, it goes: negative, negative, positive. - - +. Why does this lead to the opposite calculation?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, we have
$$
\cos(a - b) - \cos(a + b) = 2 \sin(a) \sin(b).
$$
As your book indicates, we can define
$$
u = a - b, \quad v = a + b,
$$
which can be solved for $a$ and $b$ to yield
$$
a = \frac {u + v}2, \quad b = \frac {v - u}{2} = - \frac{u - v}{2}.
$$
The correct solution for $b$ has the negative sign that you were missing.

Now starting with the identity in terms of $a$ and $b$, substitute the first pair of equations into the left hand side, and substitute the second set of equations into the right hand side. We end up with
$$
\cos(u) - \cos(v) = 2 \sin\left(\frac{u + v}{2}\right)\sin\left( -\frac{u - v}{2}\right)
\\ = 
-2 \sin\left(\frac{u + v}{2}\right)\sin\left( \frac{u - v}{2}\right).
$$

Comment: Thanks! But now I have another question. If I make u = a+b and b = a-b, then it doesn't work. I end up with a = u+v / 2 and b = u-v / 2. It feels that picking what will be equal to u and equal to v are arbitrary, and that their manipulations should all equal the same answers. What am I missing?

Comment: @visualbread In that case, you end up with the formula
$$
\cos(v) - \cos(u) = 2 \sin((u+v)/2)\sin((u-v)/2),
$$
which is equivalent to what we want. In particular, the left hand side is $-(\cos(u) - \cos(v))$.

Comment: I apologize for being dense. I trust you that what I have produced is -(cos(u)-cos(v)), I just don't see how exactly. As I said, to me, picking what a+b and a-b equal is arbitrary. Make it u or v, it doesn't matter. And from there, choosing to add or subtract these forms from one another is another arbitrary step. All we want to do is isolate a and b, so who cares?? Yet, your steps produce a -2 and my steps don't.

Comment: @visualbread Note that
$$
-(\cos(u) - \cos(v)) = -\cos(u) + \cos(v) = \cos(v) - \cos(u).
$$

Comment: I see that. I just don't see how my work produces that or why it matters? Based on everything I've seen, I should be able to set a-b equal to u or v, and nothing should happen. I should be able to add and subtract them to isolate variables, and either method should be valid. Process should not dictate outcome here. Yet it does. To me, on my end, it produces the cos(a)-cos(b) form, but to you, is produces the -(cos(a)-cos(b)) form. There is a super critical step or piece of information about how I'm doing these operations that I am missing.

Comment: @visualbread I don't know what you're asking at this point. If set $u = a-b, v = a + b$ and substitute, then you should (if you solve for $a$ and $b$ correctly) end up with
$$
\cos(u) - \cos(v) = -2 \sin\left(\frac{u + v}{2}\right)\sin\left( \frac{u - v}{2}\right).
$$
If you use $u = a + b$ and $v = a-b$ instead, then you should end up with
$$
\cos(v) - \cos(u) = 2 \sin\left(\frac{u + v}{2}\right)\sin\left( \frac{u - v}{2}\right).
$$
We can see that this equivalent to what we got the other way by multiplying both sides by $-1$. In that sense, the outcome is the same no matter what.

Comment: I don't even know what my hangup is anymore honestly. I think I just need to go to sleep and look at this with a new set of eyes in the morning. I think all the conversions between a, b, u, vs and their combinations is what's doing me in somehow. I may just opt to memorize this identity and be done with it.

Answer (score 0):

From complex expressions of $\sin x$ and $\cos x$:

$\sin x =\frac{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}{2i}$, $\cos x =\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$

$2\sin \frac{a+b}{2}\sin \frac{a-b}{2} =2(\frac{e^{^{i\frac{a+b}{2}}}-e^{-{i\frac{a+b}{2}}}}{2i})(\frac{e^{{i\frac{a-b}{2}}}-e^{{-i\frac{a-b}{2}}}}{2i})$

$2\sin \frac{a+b}{2}\sin \frac{a-b}{2} =2\frac{(e^{ia}+e^{-ia})-(e^{ib}+e^{-ib})}{4i^2}=-(\cos a-\cos b)$=$\cos b-\cos a$

Answer (score 0):

Develop the right side:

$$-2\sin\frac{a+b}2\,\sin\frac{a-b}2=-2\left[\sin\frac a2\cos\frac b2+\sin\frac b2\cos\frac a2\right]\left[\sin\frac a2\cos\frac b2-\sin\frac b2\cos\frac a2\right]=$$

$$\stackrel{\text{squares difference}}=-2\left[\sin^2\frac a2\,\cos^2\frac b2-\sin^2\frac b2\,\cos^2\frac a2\right]=$$

$$=-2\left[\left(1-\cos^2\frac a2\right)\cos^2\frac b2-\left(1-\cos^2\frac b2\right)\cos^2\frac a2\right]=$$

$$=-2\left[\cos^2\frac b2-\cos^2\frac a2\right]=-2\left[\cos^2\frac b2-\sin^2\frac b2+\sin^2\frac b2-\cos^2\frac a2+\sin^2\frac a2-\sin^2\frac a2\right]=$$

$$=-2\left[\cos b-\cos a+\sin^2\frac b2-\sin^2\frac a2\right]=-2\left[\cos b-\cos a-\left(\frac12-\sin^2\frac b2\right)+\frac12-\sin^2\frac a2\right]=$$

$$=-2\left[\cos b-\cos a-\frac12\cos b+\frac12\cos a\right]=\cos a-\cos b$$

We used several times in the above the super-identity

$$\cos2x=\begin{cases}\cos^2x-\sin^2 x\\{}\\2\cos^2 x-1\\{}\\1-2\sin^2x\end{cases}$$

Can you spot the places where we used this?